# HTML & CSS Layout float issue

Tags: html, css

This is basically the site http://funkz.nfshost.com/
The bottom post with `<div id="big-post"></div>` element is floated to the left,
and the sidebar with `<aside id="tab-lists"></aside>` element is floated to the right,
but when i add another(or more) `<div id="big-post">` element after the first one it moves the whole sidebar down with the post...
I've tried clearing, but nothing helped...I'm pretty sure the solution is simple, can someone help me?

Comment: You cannot add more then one _big-post_. You are using the `id` tag, so the id must be unique. If you have more the one _big-post_ element you must use `class`

Comment: I know that, it's just for testing.

Comment: We can do the right things also for testing ;) Wrong code styling sometimes hides some bugs

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="some_new_div">
  <div id="big-post">...</div> 
  <div id="big-post">...</div> 
  <div id="big-post">...</div> 
</div>
<aside id="tab-lists"></aside>
```

CSS

```
.some_new_div{float: left;}
```

Remove float from big-post and then take a new element,  inside that- put big-post element

Answer (score 0):

Right-floated elements have to be placed before other elements, so you have to do something like this:

```
....
<aside id="tab-lists"></aside>
<div id="big-post"></div>
<div id="big-post"></div>
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that was the first thing i tried, but when I do it this way, when I duplicate the sidebar the big-post is being pushed down. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `<aside id="tab-lists"></aside>` element needs to occur **before** any of the`<div id="big-post">` elements.

I've just moved it above the post div in chrome developer tools and could add another post successfully.

Comment: Yes, but when I add another `<aside>` it pushes the  down the `<div id="big-post">`

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. Thought you were just having the one aside. See Chandrakant's answer.

Answer (score 0):

right goes over left in this case, your aside needs to be moved up in the chain, in this case above the big-post.